# Does bootstrap hidden-sm effect SEO consequences

Tags: seo, css, mobile, hidden-text, bootstrap

So hiding text can be seen by Google as a black hat SEO trick, that's what I have read on many articles out there. So when a user is viewing my website on their mobile, There are usually a few things I think they don't need to see.

As a developer that uses Bootstrap, I often use the class `hidden-xs` or `visible-lg` which hides elements on the page using `display: none`. When using hidden I'm concerned about the SEO consequences.

*Question(s):*

*When using `hidden-` will Google consider this blackhat and punish the site?*

Answer (score 2):

Google does not [punish sites with hidden elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16816016/1892635), in fact its been like this for several years. Nowadays Google is much smarter than it was a decade ago, their bots are able to understand a great deal of standard JavaScript scripts, CSS code and modern CSS3 stylesheets.

Google rarely punishes sites for hiding text because [keyword stuffing no longer works](https://moz.com/beginners-guide-to-seo/myths-and-misconceptions-about-search-engines) as it once did. However hidden elements that have no way of being un-hidden will not be counted towards the page content.

*Googlebot can make sense of:*

- JavaScript triggers (`onclick`, `jQuery`, `MooTools`, `DoJo` etc)
- CSS3 Viewpoint triggers (`@Media, Screen etc`)
- CSS Triggers (`focus`, `hover`, `active` etc)

*Bootstraps uses the following CSS media queries to hide elements:*

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .hidden-xs {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .hidden-sm {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
  .hidden-md {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .hidden-lg {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Google will make sense of the [media queries](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/responsive/fundamentals/use-media-queries?hl=en) and know what content is hidden in which mode.

Comment: 100 % agree, Google is pretty good on that :)